# Get number of elements made with .enter()

Tags: d3.js, selection

I want to center to my legendar vertically, however in order to do that I need to know how many new nodes are created with `.enter()` so that I can use this value in the transform each of each `<g>` subnode.

How would I do that?

Comment: `selection.enter().size()` will give you an integer corresponding to the number of entering items. Conversely you could use `selection.size() - data.length`, where `data` is the parameter for `selection.data(data)`.

Comment: @JSBob How would I go about using that inside an existing `enter()` section (for use in `.attr(...)`)?

Comment: All you have to do is store it in a variable: `var selectEnter = elem.selectAll("g").data(data).enter(); selectEnter.append("g").attr("y", selectEnter.size())` where `elem` is the parent element.